# How can I make all Windows 7 folders show in the same view mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have Windows 7 and I am wondering how to make all items in a folder show up in the detail view by default. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

### Using Windows Explorer

1. Find a folder that has the view that you want or pick a folder that you want to change.
2. Follow the instructions from [To apply the current view setting to other folders](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-folder-options#section_3):

   > 1. Open a folder, click the arrow next to the **Views** button [image] on the toolbar, and choose a view setting.
   > 2. On the toolbar, click **Organize**, and then click **Folder and search options**.
   > 3. In the **Folder Options** dialog box, click the **View** tab, click **Apply to Folders**, click **Yes**, and then click **OK**.

   [image]

### Using the Registry Editor

1. Start the Registry Editor `regedit.exe`.
2. Go to the key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
   ```
3. Delete the `Bags` key.

   [image]

   > **Note**: There also seem to be other registry keys that may be related to this issue. Vistax64 [lists these keys](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/70819-windows-explorer-folder-view-settings.html):
   >
   > - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU`
   > - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags`
   > - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
   > - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
   > - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

   Please refer to their article to determine how to remove (and re-create) these keys.

### Using `REG`

1. Run the following command

   ```
   REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /f
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I was still getting inconsistent results with the various solutions. This 
seemed to work best for me:

1. Open My Documents folder, Select View - Details
2. Either (A) move Date column to the far left or (B) right click on date column, select "More" and move Date to the very top (Move Up button)
3. Click on Date to sort by most recent
4. Select View - Options
5. Select View tab, Apply to all folders

This will always sort folders for that document type by date since it is the first column and saved as default view.