# Windows 7 Forces Detail View of all folders

Tags: windows-7

About a week ago I started to have an issue, every folder on any drive is in detail view, if I change to any other view like icons, then I press back and the folder again it just reverts back to detail view.

Things I tried:

I googled the problem and saw a possible fix in the registry with the Bags and BagMRU keys, I tried the fix both manually and with the script provided, they didn't work.

Then I tried Organize > Folder and search options, where if I change the view to icons and press "Apply to all folders" it does make all folders in icons view, but same as before, if I change a folder to another view it will revert back to icons. If I press the "reset" it just goes back to the detail view behavior.

Does anyone have any idea what could I try next to solve this issue?

Comment: I would recommend first resetting all stored settings related to the Explorer folder views, as outline in this related question: http://superuser.com/questions/90852/how-can-i-make-all-windows-7-folders-show-in-the-same-view-mode

Comment: As stated in the question, already tried to reset those registry settings with no luck.

Comment: In case you deleted those keys in the registry, there are also some keys that might need to be re-created, as mentioned on [How to Reset Windows Explorer Folder View Settings to Make Vista Remember](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/70819-windows-explorer-folder-view-settings.html). My reasoning would be, if the keys don't exist, no new *view* setting can be stored.

Comment: I followed the link step by step, still no result, but i did observe a new thing, i booted in safe mode, and in safe mode everything works like it should. Question is now, are some parts of registery not loaded or ignored when booting in safe mode ? Or there might be an application that forces the detail view, although i didn't install new software and most software i have it's pretty mainstream stuff.

Comment: Good catch! You might also be able to create a new user account and see if it suffers the same problem. Maybe the problem is tied only to your user account. This could narrow down the problem further.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was in vacation, but indeed creating a new user does solve the problem for that user. So now i wonder how can this be fixed for the current user ? Or just make a new user and move all info ?

Comment: I really have no clue what it could be specifically. But it seems like it's tied to your user account only. So possibly, it's a running application that actively changes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to sum up and close the question.

With the help of Oliver Salzburg i came up to the following solution: I created a new user and logged off the main user profile i used, then i used the Windows Easy Transfer to make a backup of the main user, deleted the main user afterwards and restored it with the backup i made. Now the problem is solved and everything seems to work fine.