# Having Windows 7 "Sort by File Type" by default

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make all Windows 7 folders show in the same view mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/90852/how-can-i-make-all-windows-7-folders-show-in-the-same-view-mode)

I use to have a XP desktop, which I had set so that when I went into a folder, the default way it would sort said folders contents would be by file type. Now with my windows 7 laptop, thats not the case - It sorts by Name by default.

This is a bit of a pain, because I can find files and folders a lot faster when going by file type and then by name, rather by name. Is there anyway I can set windows 7 to sort by file type by default?

Right now I'm having to click "Type" to have it sort for every "New" folder (that is a folder I have not gone in before, and thus sorted by name), which I dont really like.

Comment: No its not, as with James Young first answer (before changes), that question related to the VIEW of folders, this relates to the SORT BY of folders. In fact both the answer (at one of them) in that question even has the same link as provided by James Young first answer (before changes)

Comment: Ah however to give credit, the answer is the change. However I think this question should remain open (or rather, not closed as a duplicate) because it does relate to Sort By rather than Folder View

Comment: Making the changes stick is what is important, and the method is exactly the same. Essentially, set up a folder the way you like it, then duplicate view across all other folders of the same type/template. If you want *every* folder to look alike, set them all to use the same template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure you have only one Explorer window open. Right click on an empty space of a folder and select “View – List”, then right click again and select “Sort by – Type” (if you don’t see the “Type” option, click on “More…” at the end of Sort Options and in the list that appears find the “Type” option and bring it to the top of the list.)

2) Press the alt key to release the top menu of Explorer, and go to “Tools – Folder Options”. Go to the second tab (“View”) of the dialogue box that appears, and press the “Apply to Folders” button. You will be asked to confirm; do it.

3) Close the window by pressing the Ctrl key and (with this key pressed) clicking the x button at the right top of Windows Explorer.

Comment: This does not do what I want. The link relates to changing the default VIEW(s) of all folders, not the default SORT BY. In all of template images, they all sort by name, which is what I want to change

Comment: Will update, one moment.