# Can not change default explorer sorting option

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, sorting, default-settings

Like the title says: I am not able to change the default sorting option in windows explorer. At the moment folders and files are sorted by *date modified*, but I'd like to change this to *sorted by name*. I followed the answer in [Having Windows 7 "Sort by File Type" by default](https://superuser.com/questions/523456/having-windows-7-sort-by-file-type-by-default) (adapted to *sort by name*). But after closing windows explorer and opening it again, all files and folders are sorted by *date modified*.

How can I change the default sorting option?

Comment: Did you click on Apply to Folders in the Folder Options > View tab?

Comment: Of course I did. Although in my German windows 7 version the button is called *Für Ordner übernehmen*, I think I've pressed the correct button. ;-)

Comment: I followed each step you mentioned, but your proposed solution does not work for me.

Comment: Thank you, I only need to execute this batch file. Afterwards sorting option is *sorted by name*. The steps mentioned above would be necessary if I'd like to set another sorting option than *sorted by name* to default sorting. Could you please write an answer with this solution, so that I can mark it as *working solution*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset all folder view settings to the default using the following [batch file](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15692-folder-view-settings-reset-all-default.html):

```
@echo off

:: To reset all folders to default folder views
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F

:: To reset Windows Photo Viewer position
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Viewer" /VA /F

:: To kill and restart explorer
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Afterwards if required you can specify the folder template via folder Properties > Customize tab, then change the sort order and *Apply to Folders* from the Folder Options > View tab.